# How do you compare an existing table to a dictionary using hive

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive

Currently I am working with large amounts of input(twitter) and trying to run some basic sentiment analysis using Apache Hive. However, I cannot figure out how to compare the table I have of tweetids and body strings. I'll do my best to explain below:

I have two external storage tables called TwitterLoc and TwitterNo then this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dict (word text, score int)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("cassandra.ks.name"="myKeyspace", "cassandra.port"=9160);
```

--Goal table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE results(tweetid string, score int)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("cassandra.ks.name"="twitterverse")
```

--Join the tables and their relevant info into one table

```
DROP IF EXISTS twitter;
CREATE TABLE TWITTER(tweetid string, body string)
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE twitter
SELECT tweetid, body
FROM twitterLoc;

INSERT INTO TABLE twitter
select tweetid, body
from twitterNo;
```

From here I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Split up each tweet (called body in the twitter table) into individual words for comparison.
2. Compare the words with my dictionary to get the "score"
3. Group the scores again by tweetid
   and this is how I have attempted to do that:

   ```
   --Compare to dictionary
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS twitterSplit;
   CREATE TABLE twitterSplit(tweetid string, word text)
   STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE

   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE twitterSplit
   SELECT tweetid, SPLIT(body, " ")
   FROM twitter;

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scoreTable
   CREATE TABLE scoreTable(tweetid string, word text, score int)
   STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;

   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE scoreTable
   Select twitterSplit.tweetid, twitterSplit.word, Dict.score
   FROM twitterSplit JOIN Dict WHERE word = word;

   --Report Scores

   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE results
   SELECT tweetid, SUM(score) by tweetid
   FROM ScoreTable
   GROUP BY tweetid;
   ```

Comment: When posting on Stack Overflow, you should ask a question which shows what you have tried to solve your own problems and states a specific issue you are having with your code. It seems like you are just asking someone to do the next step for you.

Comment: Hi Savanna, thank you for the input and i'm sorry that I didnt present my question very well, i've attempted the coding and added that above but as a part of that I have no clue how to attempt summation so in sort of a pseudo code way I just wrote SUM. Hope that clears it up a bit